# bootstrap calender not displaying after adding the date input

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

i am using a bootstrap calender on todo. and when user click on the "add more button" a date input added automatic.

---

the issue is when i click on add new button its added a input but the calender not displaying. and on the same place when i simple hard coded the input the calender shows.

```
 var htt=$('#dd').html();

        var objTo = document.getElementById('subtodo');
var divtest = document.createElement("div");
divtest.innerHTML = htt;

objTo.appendChild(divtest)




<div id="subtodo"></div>


    <div id="dd">


    <input type="text" name="list[]" style="height:30px !important;">

 Due date:  <input class="m-wrap m-ctrl-medium date-picker" size="16" type="text" placeholder="Date" name="due[]" id="datepicker" style="height:30px !important;">

    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds to me like you just need to run the datepicker init function again once you've appended a new one to the DOM.

Answer (score 0):

if you are appending dynamic input for datepicker, you need to reinitialize the datepicker  just after the JavaScript you have written to append the input box.

Example:

```
    $('#dd').datepicker();
```

Comment: can you please share a demo link